# Vmovntpd instruction on Intel Xeon Platinum 8168 CPU

Tags: performance, assembly, intel, avx, cpu-cache

I have a simple vector-vector addition algorithm implementation in assembly. It uses AVX to read 4 doubles from the A vector, and 4 doubles from B vector. The algorithm adds these numbers and writes the result back to the C vector. If I use vmovntpd to write back the result, the performance becames extremely random. I have made this test on an azure server, with Intel Xeon Platinum 8168 CPU. If I run this test on my laptop (Intel Core i7-2640M CPU), this random effect disappears. What is the problem on the server? One more info: The server has 44 CPU-s.

[Edit]
Here is my code:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Dense to dense
;; Without cache (for storing the result)
;; AVX-512
;; Without tolerances
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

global _denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux
_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux:

push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
; c = a + lambda * b
; rdi: address1
; rsi: address2
; rdx: address3
; rcx: count
; xmm0: lambda

mov     rax, rcx
shr     rcx, 4
and     rax, 0x0F

vzeroupper

vmovupd  zmm5, [abs_mask]

sub     rsp, 8
movlpd  [rbp - 8], xmm0
vbroadcastsd    zmm7, [rbp - 8]
vmovapd  zmm6, zmm7

cmp     rcx, 0
je      after_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux

start_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux:

vmovapd  zmm0, [rdi] ; a
vmovapd  zmm1, zmm7
vmulpd   zmm1, zmm1, [rsi] ; b
vaddpd   zmm0, zmm0, zmm1  ; zmm0 = c = a + b
vmovntpd  [rdx], zmm0

vmovapd  zmm2, [rdi + 64] ; a
vmovapd  zmm3, zmm6
vmulpd   zmm3, zmm3, [rsi + 64] ; b
vaddpd   zmm2, zmm2, zmm3  ; zmm2 = c = a + b
vmovntpd  [rdx + 64], zmm2

add     rdi, 128
add     rsi, 128
add     rdx, 128

loop    start_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux

after_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux:

cmp     rax, 0
je      end_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux

mov     rcx, rax

last_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux:

movlpd  xmm0, [rdi] ; a
movapd  xmm1, xmm7
mulsd   xmm1, [rsi] ; b
addsd   xmm0, xmm1  ; xmm0 = c = a + b
movlpd  [rdx], xmm0

add     rdi, 8
add     rsi, 8
add     rdx, 8

loop    last_loop_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux

end_denseToDenseAddAVX512_nocache_64_linux:

mov     rsp, rbp
pop     rbp
ret
```

Comment: Are you grouping your stores into full cache lines?  Or are you mixing loads and NT stores arbitrarily?  Could easily be a problem especially if your virtual server runs your code on the same physical core as another non-idle thread.  To say any more we need a [mcve] of your code and how you compiled it (compiler/version/options), or at least the asm for the inner loop.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you use AVX512 on the Xeon Platinum, so you can do full-line NT stores with a single instruction, making partial-line early flushes impossible?

Comment: The same happens with AVX512 too. And of course, is store 8 doubles on a full cache line.
I use nasm 2.14.02, and gcc 4.9.2.

Comment: Here is my code:
https://pastebin.com/8u5J0xT5

Comment: You should post your code within the question itself! Do you intentionally use legacy SSE instructions after the main loop? (`movlpd  xmm0, [rdi]` will introduce a false dependency.) Do you intentionally avoid FMA instructions? Why are you copying so much instead of exploiting the 3 register operands? The `vmovupd  zmm5, [abs_mask]` at the beginning is never used.

Comment: "Do you intentionally use legacy SSE instructions after the main loop?" I use them for the reamining (lass than 16) numbers. But the problem holds if I skip this part. I do not use FMA, because I have other variant of this code which uses absolute and relative tolerances on the + operation (if the result is too small, it becomes zero), and I want to compare this "naive" version with that versions. 3  register operands: I've just "ported" the old SSE2 versions to AVX and AVX512, and SSE2 has no 2 register operands.

Comment: @Pocokman Stack Overflow questions must be self-contained.  Edit your question to add your code.  I am not going to have a look at external sites to gather bits and pieces of your question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've inserted my code.

Comment: Consider rewriting your code in C/C++ using intrinsics. A compiler won't make basic mistakes like using the LOOP instruction.

Comment: One problem is that there is no `vzeroupper` before you use SSE instructions.  A `vzeroupper` instruction should be placed at the end of each section of AVX instructions to avoid partial register penalties.  Alternatively, translate these instructions into AVX instructions and issue `vzeroupper` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution! This is a NUMA architecture with 44 CPUs, so I disabled the NUMA, and I've limited the number of online cpu-s to 1 with the following kernel parameters: numa=off maxcpus=1 nr_cpus=1.

Comment: That's *a* solution but hardly a useful one.  You might as well just buy a desktop Skylake-X instead of a 44-core Xeon if you only want to use a single core.  This is more like a step in narrowing down the problem, e.g. that NUMA might be the problem.  Does using `taskset` to pin your program to a single core help when running with all CPUs active?

Comment: Using an azure server (for at most 10 hours) was cheaper than buying a new CPU or computer, but I'll remember this Skylake-X, thank you :)

Comment: Surely you can pay less for a single-CPU VM instance if you choose not to multi-thread?